# Why is selenium-webdriver (LiveServerTestCase) still pointing at the wrong database?

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm using Selenium to run some integration tests for a Django app (using `postgres` for the development database).

I set-up the tests by creating a Model object.  The tests then interact with the object through the browser (`selenium-webdriver`), or directly through database queries.

The tests that use `webdriver` cannot access the Model object.  The database queries can.

I've come to the conclusion that `webdriver` is not being pointed at the correct database.

I've tried using `LiveServerTestCase` both explicitly giving it the port and URL I want to use (`localhost:8001`) and using `live_server_url` to allow it to decide for itself.  Neither have worked.

Here's the form being tested - it's a simple select from a list of objects.

`forms.py`

```py
class FooForm(form.Form):
    foo = forms.ModelChoice.Field(
                required=False,
                label='select',
                queryset=Foo.objects.all(),
                widget=forms.Select(),
                )
```

Here's the DB settings.

`settings.py`

```py
DATABASES = {
        'default':{
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
                'NAME': 'app',
                'USER': 'user',
                'PASSWORD': 'password',
                'HOST': 'localhost',
                'PORT': '',
                }
              }
```

Here are the tests.

`test.py`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.select import Select
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from app.models import Foo

class BasicTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        foo = Foo.objects.create(name='test_foo')
        self.selenium = webdriver.Firefox()
        super(BasicTestCase, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.quit()
        super(BasicTestCase, self).tearDown()

    def test_can_interact_via_db_query(self):
        self.assertEqual(Foo.objects.get(id=1).name, 'test_foo')

    def test_can_interact_via_webdriver_query(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' %(self.live_server_url, '/page/'))
        elem = Select(self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_foo'))
        foo_name = elem.select_by_index(0)
        self.assertEqual(foo_name, 'test_foo')
```

I'd expect both of these tests to pass.

I can see the browser being opened and the page being interacted with.

`test_can_interact_via_db_query` passes.

`test_can_interact_via_webdriver_query` fails with an assertion error `None != test_foo`.

Comment: Try to delete *.pyc files

Comment: @Wonka - thanks for the speedy suggestion, but I still have the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd fundamentally misunderstood what was happening here with the Select object.  I was simply selecting the item, not interrogating it.  No database issues involved.

Here's a crude working version of the test

```
def test_can_interact_via_webdriver_query(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' %(self.live_server_url, '/page/'))
        elem = Select(self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_foo'))
        things = [o.text for o in elem.options]
        found = False
        for thing in things:
            if thing == 'test_foo':
                found = True

        self.assertTrue(found)
```